# Windows form project is not showing any data from my embedded MS Access DB after installation

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, ms-access

I am a beginner and I want to use MS Access DB inside my Windows form Project. My mdb file is showing data when I run it in debug mode. Once I create an exe and install it, it is not showing any data. The database is not password protected.

In App.config this is the connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: can u show as the path of the DB you given?

Comment: @AbiTom I have added the connection string

Comment: can u try direct path something like Data Source="C:\\mydb.mdb" and let me know

Comment: If I use the above path then it means that the mdb file is not embedded but I want to embed the mdb file inside my windows form project

Comment: if the direct path works I think this is the issue please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the .mdb file in my setup project.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you use "Data Source=|DataDirectory|" install & run the application,for example it looks for DB in C:\MyApp\Data\ folder. It should be C:\MyApp without additional \Data folder.

You need to call the AppDomain.SetData method to specify where the |DataDirectory| points to

```
    var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string relative = @"..\..\App_Data\";
    string absolute = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(baseDirectory, relative));
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", absolute);
```

Comment: Since I am using windows form application, it does not contain Global.asax file. One more thing I don't have access to Server.MapPath(). It is not a web application.

Comment: sorry u can set it in the Program main class

Comment: Yes I have added that in Program.cs but what about Server.MapPath() ?